# Could-be-computer accessories on SuperUser?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about accessories (specifically, MicroSD cards) that may or may not be used with a computer allowed on SuperUser?

Comment: Shopping you say? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/should-shopping-and-or-hardware-recommendation-questions-be-allowed-on-superuser

Comment: Take away the second line and it's no longer a dupe of the shopping.

Comment: I think something like "Do SDHC cards work on SD readers?" would be an appropriate question, or perhaps questions related to read/write speed. If it's about prices, though, probably not. Ask and see if it lasts.

Comment: depends on the specific question; if it's about, say, technical details about general MicroSD, i'd say it's fair game; if it's about whether this or that MicroSD product will work with this or that mp3/phone/etc device, it's probably offtopic.  you're welcome to try it and see; don't be offended if it gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "like for smartphone questions": If it involves a computer, this concerns Super User.

Accessories like memory cards are even less ambiguous in my opinion, because you can't really do something with your memory card alone. Smartphones are often on a grey area because they more or less "work like small computers on their own".

I can find more appropriate places for a smartphone question, you can imagine something specific to it. There are StackExchange sites specialized about them. I can't, however, imagine of another place to ask questions about computer accessories than Super User. They fall under the "computer hardware".

I agree however that memory cards could be in a grey area, as you can use them specifically with something else. But simply, if your question is generic about them, and would concern computers as well, then it is ok on SU.